# Android sequence layout

Tags: android, layout

I need to add buttons one by one on layout like in image below.
Similar as when text added in textArea.
Which layout I should use?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use a vertical LinearLayout and nested horizontal LinearLayouts.
You can also use Relative layout by defining the reation of each element with the previous one.

But I would highly suggest you to use *ConstraintLayout* You can achieve any kind of layout with ConstraintLayout.

I suggest you take a look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

and also a nice explanation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/